# How to use TableGenerator strategy on gorm-standalone/grails

Tags: spring-boot, grails, grails-orm

For legacy compatibility reasons, I am trying to apply the code below logic on gorm-standalone 5 or grails 3.1.16

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "book_generator")
@TableGenerator(name="book_generator", table="id_generator", schema="bookstore")
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long id;
```

The following code is the one I am struggling with

```
package helloworld

class Book {

    Integer id
    String name
    String author

    static constraints = {
        id column: 'book_id'
        name blank: false
    }
    static mapping = {
        table 'BOOKTABLE'
        version false
        // id( generator: 'hilo', params: [table: 'BOOK_SEQ', column: 'next_value', max_lo: 1, initial_value: 1, increment_size: 1 ])
        id( generator: 'table', strategy: 'enhanced-table', parameters: [name: 'table_name', value: 'BOOK_SEQ', column: 'next_value', initial_value: 1, increment_size: 1 ])

    }
}
```

Is it possible? How?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you are trying to do in Grails 3.1.16 (with either hibernate4 or hibernate5). Start by ensuring your schema is created at start-up by adding to your `application.yml` file.

```
#Add this to any sample apps if you want the schema

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS bookstore
```

Then your domain class should look like the following.

```
// Works in Grails 3.1.16 with Hibernate4 or Hibernate5

class BookGormTableSequence {

    String name
    String author

    static mapping = {
        version false
        id column: "book_id",
                generator: "enhanced-table",
                params: [schema: "BOOKSTORE", table_name: "BOOK_SEQ", initial_value: 300]
    }
}
```

If you want to use just a sequence which should provide better performance you can do the following instead

```
//Works in Grails 3.1.16, 3.2.x, and 3.3.x

class BookGormSequence {

    String name
    String author

    static mapping = {
        version false
        id column: "book_id", generator: "sequence", params: [sequence_name: "bookGormseq", initial_value: 200]
    }
}
```

Moving forward to Grails 3.2+ the `generator: "enhanced-table"` is no longer supported in Gorm 6.0 or 6.1. The "sequence" generator will work in all tested versions. Once Gorm 6.1.x is available JPA Mapping is [supported](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/whatsNew/manual/index.html). This means that your original syntax will work with little to no modifications.

```
// Table Sequence as in your question
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
class BookJpaTableSequence {

    @Id
    @TableGenerator(name="book_generator", table="BOOK_SEQ", schema="bookstore", initialValue = 55)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "book_generator")
    @Column(name = "book_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    Long id
    String name
    String author
}
```

Using a normal sequence with JPA annotations

```
// Normal Sequence - Should be more performant.
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
class BookJpaSequence {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "book_generator", sequenceName = "bookJpaSeq", initialValue = 500)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "book_generator")
    @Column(name = "book_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    Long id
    String name
    String author
}
```